# In a group $G$, if $a^3=e$ for all $a$ belongs to $G$, then is $G$ abelian?

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, abelian-groups

It's easy to show that $G$ is abelian if $a^2=e.$

Can't seem to figure out how to prove/disprove this.

Answer (score 5):

The standard counterexample is the group of matrices of the form
$$\pmatrix{1&a&b\\0&1&c\\0&0&1}$$
over the field of three elements.